# Check if an IP access a page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

We set the access control on .htaccess. For example,

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
Allow from 1.2.3.4
```

We would like to know if it is possible to check if other IP, aside from 1.2.3.4, is accessing our page.
Will it still be logged on access_log or does it have a different log file?

Comment: Why not just access the page from another IP and check if it shows up in the access log or not?

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana - In everyday speak, they are used interchangeably when talking about IP addresses so I seriously doubt anyone won't understand what we mean.

Answer (score 2):

> The Allow, Deny, and Order directives, provided by mod_access_compat,
>   are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid
>   using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.
>
> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

You should instead be using Require, as seen in the link above.

**Example of using require and only allow local clients to view site:**

```
<Directory "path/to/denied">
    Require ip 192.168
</Directory>
```

When using require, if someone tries to go your site and they don't have authorization it will be logged in your error log along with their IP, what they were trying to access and a referrer.

**Example of log:**

```
[Mon Mar 02 06:30:55.554682 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 1111:tid 1111] [client 0.0.0.0:000] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/path/to/denied, referer: http://0.0.0.0:80/index.php
```

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana What? If you don't mind, are you able to link something that explains this in more detail or give me something I can search?

Comment: I assume they mean that "IP" only means Internet Protocol, not the address specifically. However, people are using them interchangeably (since it's more common for people to talk about the addresses and not the protocol itself) so I think the distinction here is over pedantic (just my opinion)

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana - I seriously doubt that any "technical people" would be confused about us using IP instead of IP address here since it's pretty obvious what we mean by the context. If anything caused confusion, it was your comments (which didn't even explain the difference but just pointed out that there is one).